# drop SQL Server schema

Tags: sql-server, database

I understand that you cannot simply drop an SQL server schema, you must first of all drop all the objects contained therein. I found this [stored proc](http://docs.google.com/View?id=dgwxbk97_155c5dpjqcc) that performs the task of dropping all objects and then the schema itself.

Is there really no simpler way to drop a schema? Ideally, I'd like to find a way to do this without using a stored proc.

Also, it seems like the stored proc will cause errors if the schema name provided does not exist. I would like it to simply do nothing instead. I guess this is simply a matter of putting this pseudocode at the top of the script

```
IF @SchemaName NOT EXISTS
    QUIT
```

Can someone convert this into language that SQL Server will understand?

Comment: I am not a real keyboard so brief answer .I think you can Transfer objects to different schema and then drop the schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove all objects in the schame before dropping it or migrate all objects to a new schema. There is no "wildcard" option for either

To exit a stored procedure before any further processing...

```
IF SCHEMA_ID(@SchemaName) IS NULL
    RETURN
```

Answer (score 4):

The following at the top of the script should help:

```
IF SCHEMA_ID(@SchemaName) IS NULL 
    RETURN
```

[SCHEMA_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188797.aspx) returns the schema ID associated with a schema name, and [RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) exits unconditionally from a query or procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists(select * from sys.schemas where name = @SchemaName)
begin
    -- Your work
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must drop all objects before dropping the schema.
To check if a schema exists:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE CATALOG_NAME='YOUR DB NAME HERE' and SCHEMA_NAME=@SchemaName)
BEGIN
     -- Do some processing...
     return
END
```